# Does Google Cloud SQL has an RPO, RTO and ERT guide online?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Azure SQL has provided their DR's capabilities https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-business-continuity in term of RPO and RTO benchmark.

I am looking for the same on Google's Cloud SQL but can't find any information on the same. If I enable HA on Cloud SQL, and I need RTO = 1 hour and RPO < 1 hour, is this achievable?

Answer (score 2):

I think that they have [High Availability on Cloud SQL, you can check this link [1]](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#HA-configuration), and also they have a document on [Disaster Recovery Scenarios for Data [2]](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/dr-scenarios-for-data#managed-database-services-on-gcp), but I don't find specific numbers, the only thing to be consistent is the SLA.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#HA-configuration

[2] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/dr-scenarios-for-data#managed-database-services-on-gcp

Comment: Thank you I've checked both docs, there is no published info. Hopefully there are official guide in the future. But the HA feature in region should be sufficient to establish an RPO < 5s and RTO < 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

This was published in may 2021:
https://cloud.google.com/architecture/disaster-recovery/product-commitments/may25-2021

In the event of Zone Failure, RTO=15min and RPO=15min. In the event of region failure, RTO=1h and RPO=1h.